# How does a floating diffusion node store and clear charges?

Tags: semiconductors, floating-diffusion-amplifier

I'm currently studying CCD sensors. This article below attempts to explain how electrons are collected into a floating diffusion node, and then cleared when a reset voltage is applied to it. I don't quite understand the physics behind how the electrons actually move into the floating diffusion region. What is this region made of? is it N type, P type, both?

Here's a mind boggling diagram from ieee on an FDA: https://sscs.ieee.org/images/files/aboutus/history/ISSCC50/imagers/image_sensors_3.pdf

https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/understanding-ccd-output-signals/
[image]

Comment: Maybe the IEEE Journal article A Review of the Pinned Photodiode for CCD and CMOS Image Sensors (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6742594) by Eric Fossum would shine light on your problem; specifically, SECTION III.Structure and Device Physics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an N-channel CCD, it's N type. Structurally, it's the source of M1.

To understand it start by pulling the gate of M1 high. That forces the voltage at M1's source node (the "floating diffusion") to the reset voltage. Then pull the gate of M1 low. Now, clock the CCD to push electrons into the floating diffusion. They can't escape: M1 is off. So, they change the potential of the floating diffusion by an amount Q/C, where C is the total capacitance of the floating diffusion to the surrounding structures. M2 senses the potential, and the "correlated double sampler" downstream measures the change.

Repeat for the next pixel.

Comment: So… the floating diffusion is simply the source of M1?

Comment: @BobaJFET You may think of it that way if you please. Or, you can think of it as a diode whose anode is the substrate. Or even as the drain of the CCD register considered as a multi-gate MOSFET. It's a bit of N-doped silicon surrounded by gates and channel stops.

Comment: I found this from analog devices. Is this the same concept shown in figure 1? I’m familiar with charge amplifiers but i’ve never heard of a floating diffusion amplifier until now. https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/integrated-solutions-for-ccd-signal-processing.html

Comment: @BobaJFET Yes, same concept, with the N diffusion modeled as a capacitor. If you're into this signal processing stuff, you might look at https://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1980AJ.....85.1421H.

Comment: @I will certainly read that. When modeled as a capacitor it makes more sense to me. I think the concept of the diffusion being “floating” is where I lose understanding. Is the diffusion node really not connected to any return path or ground?

Comment: @BobaJFET Think of the diffusion as the top plate of a capacitor. The bottom is the chip substrate, at fixed potential, usually ground. When the reset MOSFET is off, the top plate floats.